# Networking app architecture

Tags: android, facebook, rest, network-programming, android-volley

I'm building an android app similar to a facebook app, aimed to display various information stored in a database.
I'm using on the server-side a REST API, which returns responses based on various POST requests, with a facebook token authentification.

And on the client-side, I'm using the volley library to deal with network requests. I've tried numerous possibities but I'm searching for the most elegant way of communicating with the server, and since this is a trivial case, I thought you could maybe help me with this one...

Since I'm always checking fb tokens, and making similar POST requests, I considered adding a Connexion objet, which creates a volley request when prompted with an execute(POST parameters...); method, and calls a callback method when the response has arrived.

But I'm struggling to decide whether I should create a SessionManager object (Singleton or not ?) which can process ALL the data from session related responses (like check login, login...) based maybe on codes (for example Error 5xx for every type of response), and DO the intents.

**Or** I should process these responses in every activity, and do the intents there. Knowing they can maybe repetitive.
In short, I'm looking for a best practice to apply when the app has to process common responses, and not so uncommon responses for example.
Keep all the logic in the activities ? Create objects ?
Don't hesitate to post your opinion on the subject !

Thank you very much.

EDIT : Ended up using a Connexion object to process all the requests (with volley). As for the Intents, I kept all that logic in the activities and haven't used another controller. The result was not ugly. Mainly because I used a secondary route which does the authentification, so the server ALWAYS responds with a big error if you're an evil hacker.

Comment: use android HTTp client http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html

Comment: Isn't volley more efficient ? Also, I'm asking about *how* to implement these objects (like Volley, HttpClient, AsyncTask...) in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I am not working with Volley but with the Apache HttpClient, this should not matter for your question though.
Having the code which handles the Post Requests in your Activities is a bad solution. See:
[Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Your idea with creating a SessionManager is really good though. You can handle all the stuff in the SessionManager and not bother with it in your Activities. Additionally you should add classes for different purposes than managing the session. If you get all friends from a specific user you should create a FriendsController or FriendsManager.

Processing the answers can be done in a single class too. I assume that you receive JSON from your API as response. Create one class that takes the response and returns a JSONObject.

Although it is far from perfect feel free to take a look at my app. I am currently learning Android / Java so it might not be as perfect as one might expect. The classes to handle POSTs are called YYYController and not Manager. But this is just a naming convention I use:
[My Android Project](https://github.com/Deutronomium/-Android-Alle-Neune)

Your calls can return an enum in which you store the different Callback types:

```
class Enum Callbacks {
    SUCCESS,
    CREATED,
    UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY
}
```

In your application you can use them like this:

```
Callbacks response = SessionManager.login();
if (response == Callbacks.SUCCESS) {
    //your login logic here
}
```

Comment: Amazing answer. Thank you very much !
Making the SessionManager or FriendsManager do the intents is advised or discouraged though ? Is giving all the power to these objects, and putting there the logic of interactions between activities not a bad practice maybe ?
- A developer looking for the best thing for its app :D

Comment: You should not have any logic regarding your Intents / Activities in these Managers. Their sole purpose is to get data from your server.

Comment: I added my current project in my answer. Feel free to take a look at it.

Comment: Ok. The issue is that the SessionManager only gets a callback method because the connexions are done in another object (good idea?), so it's really hard to process the responses in a SINGLE method and return answers (Ex: logout() -> launch logout connexion -> gets response in same callback of login() method...)

Should I maybe create codes for the responses (5xx User created) and do the intents in activities according to these answers ?
So for example : logout() -> callback with 505 Logged out -> Activity if sessionmanager.logout() == 505 logged out -> "Logged out!"

I don't know...

Comment: I edited my answer how to use an enum for the callback.

Comment: Cool. Will look it up !